# Java - How to put in a multi dimensional HashMap

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, hashmap

I have this three dimensional HashMap.

```
   private HashMap<Integer, HashMap<Integer, HashMap<Integer, Chunk>>> chunks = new HashMap<Integer, HashMap<Integer, HashMap<Integer, Chunk>>>();
```

When I use this to put in a 'Chunk', I get a NullPointerException.

```
chunks.get(x).get(y).put(z, new Chunk(x, y, z, param1, param2));
```

What is wrong?

Comment: You should definitely create a new `class` for modeling your "chunks", instead of keeping them in a multidimensional map.

Comment: @MickMnemonic What do you mean by modeling?

Comment: All programming is essentially creating a model of the problem you're solving. Currently your model of "chunks" is a mapping of integers into a mapping of integers to a mapping of integers to chunks; this is frankly unreadable to anyone but the author. The object-oriented way to solve the problem would be to create a new class (or a bunch of classes) which models the problem by breaking it down into smaller, more manageable chunks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your initialization you only initialize the "outer" Map. here is what you have to do:

```
private Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Chunk>>> chunks = new HashMap<Integer, Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Chunk>>>();

Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Chunk>> inner1 = new HashMap<Integer, Map<Integer, Chunk>>();
chunks.put(x, inner1);

Map<Integer, Chunk> inner2 = new HashMap<Integer, Chunk>();
inner1.put(y, inner2);

inner2.put(z, new Chunk(x, y, z, param1, param2));
```

Note that you should work with the interface 'Map' instead of the implementation 'HashMap' where possible.

Comment: I will try this.

Can you briefly explain why I rather should use Map than HashMap?

Comment: Generally you should always use the general interface definition, because methods or classes, that consume your maps, don't care what the actual implementation is. It can be a HashMap, a TreeMap or any kind of map. Then, if you want to change the implementation later, you only have to change it in one place.

Comment: @KaareZ read Effective Java by Joshua Bloch. Specifically Item 52, "Refer to objects by their interfaces". Google the chapter name, you'll also find some reasonable abstracts

Answer (score 1):

Re-model your application.

Using three levels of HashMaps means dealing with three levels of abstraction at the same time. This is very tedious and error-prone.

If you can manage to normalize your structure enough to require two levels only, you can use the [`Table`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Table.html) data structure from Google's [Guava library](https://github.com/google/guava), which is a Facade for a two-dimensional map. This data structure has already solved the problems of creating and accessing the individual map hierarchies for you, so you can concentrate on what your class actually wants to do.

If you don't want to use an external library, you will have to write a similar data structure yourself. Make sure you create it as a separate class / interface outside of your core application, and that you heavily unit test it. But mixing three levels of data structures with your core business logic means violating Cohesion, one of the fundamental principles of object oriented design.